# How to get activity details for past updates on Pulumi, using Pulumi CLI?

Tags: pulumi

If I go to `app.pulumi.com`, I can see in the browser the details for `Update #903`, for instance. It shows a summary: qty of new, modified and deleted resources. And I can also see the details, the specific resources that were created, modified, or deleted.

How can I get the same information using Pulumi CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a way to get the data you're looking for with a CLI command, but you can get the data -- at least the raw data -- with the Pulumi Service REST API: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/service-rest-api

For example, assuming you've got `curl`, `jq`, and a Pulumi access token, you could do something like this (excuse my amateur Bash), which takes the update ID and calls another API to fetch the list of raw engine events associated with the update:

```bash
get_update_id() {
    curl -s \
        -H "Accept: application/vnd.pulumi+8" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: token $PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        "https://api.pulumi.com/api/stacks/$1/$2/$3/updates/$4" | jq -r .updateID
}

get_update_events() {
    curl -s \
        -H "Accept: application/vnd.pulumi+8" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: token $PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
        "https://api.pulumi.com/api/stacks/$1/$2/$3/update/$(get_update_id $1 $2 $3 $4)/events" | jq 
}
```

Then to use it:

```bash
$ get_update_events orgname projectname stackname 1
```

But be warned! The `events` API returns a *lot* of data, so expect to spend a little time figuring out what you're looking at. It should be all there, though. (The CLI and the console understand these events natively, but unfortunately the REST API doesn't yet expose it in a way that's as tidy as you'd probably like.)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

`pulumi stack history` will show you the history of the stack

Comment: I tried using `pulumi stack history`, but (i) it paginates instead of letting me choose which version number to show and (ii) even though it shows qty of elements created/mofified/removed, it doesn't show information about which elements, as we see on `pulumi up`.

Answer (score 0):

`pulumi` support a flag that streams JSON to stdout, which is what the console is displaying:

```
pulumi up --json
```

Comment: I understand I can use that to get info about current update. But what about past updates?

Comment: I have just edited the title, to make it clear its about history, not the current update